# Byte shift issue in an integer conversion

Tags: c#, type-conversion, byte-shifting

I read 3 bytes in a binary file which I need to convert into an integer.

I use this code to read the bytes :

```
LastNum last1Hz = new LastNum();
last1Hz.Freq = 1;
Byte[] LastNumBytes1Hz = new Byte[3];
Array.Copy(lap_info, (8 + (32 * k)), LastNumBytes1Hz, 0, 3);
last1Hz.NumData = LastNumBytes1Hz[2] << 16 + LastNumBytes1Hz[1] << 8 + LastNumBytes1Hz[0];
```

`last1Hz.NumData` is an `integer`.

This seems to be the good way to convert `bytes` into `integers` in the posts i have seen.

Here is a capture of the values read:

[image]

But the integer `last1Hz.NumData` is always 0.

I'm missing something but can't figure out what.

Comment: Addition has higher priority than bit-shift.

Comment: Yes it's ok now thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use brackets (because addition has a higher priority than bit shifting):

```
int a = 0x87;
int b = 0x00;
int c = 0x00;

int x = c << 16 + b << 8 + a; // result 0
int z = (c << 16) + (b << 8) + a; // result 135
```

Your code should look like this:

```
last1Hz.NumData = (LastNumBytes1Hz[2] << 16) + (LastNumBytes1Hz[1] << 8) + LastNumBytes1Hz[0];
```

Comment: Yes thank you for that quick answer, it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is an order of precedence issue. + is evaluated before <<
Put brackets in to force the bit shift to be evaluated first.

```
 last1Hz.NumData = (LastNumBytes1Hz[2] << 16) + (LastNumBytes1Hz[1] << 8) + LastNumBytes1Hz[0];
```